# TS Как по условию добавлять поля в тип

Tags: typescript

Есть тип User c двумя ролями Trainer и Client:

```
enum UserRole {
  Trainer = 'Тренер',
  Client = 'Клиент',
}

type User = {
  userRole: UserRole,
}
```

Я хочу расширить этот тип и указать что в зависимости от того какая роль была выбрана, в этот тип будут добавлены поля из следующих интерфейсов:

```
export interface ITrainer {
  certificate: string;
  merits: string;
  personalTraining: boolean;
}

export interface IClient {
  caloriesToLose: number;
  readyToTraining: boolean;
}
```

По итогу хочу получить что-то вроде этого:

```
type User = {
  userRole: UserRole
} & User.userRole === UserRole.Trainer ? ITrainer : IClient
```

Прочитал про условные типы, но там они описаны для классов.
Может какой-нибудь `infer` тут можно использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, могу предложить сделать через дженерик

```
enum UserRole {
  Trainer = 'Тренер',
  Client = 'Клиент',
}

export interface ITrainer {
  certificate: string;
  merits: string;
  personalTraining: boolean;
}

export interface IClient {
  caloriesToLose: number;
  readyToTraining: boolean;
}

type UserExtendedType<T extends UserRole> = {
  userRole: T,
} & (T extends UserRole.Trainer ? ITrainer : IClient)

// wrong userRole
const UserExtended: UserExtendedType<UserRole.Client> = { userRole: UserRole.Trainer, certificate: 'sss' };

// unknown field
const UserExtended2: UserExtendedType<UserRole.Trainer> = { userRole: UserRole.Trainer, certificate: 'sss', unknownField: 'test' };

// field from a wrong interface
const UserExtended3: UserExtendedType<UserRole.Trainer> = { userRole: UserRole.Trainer, caloriesToLose: 'sss' };

// Non full body
const UserExtended4: UserExtendedType<UserRole.Client> = { userRole: UserRole.Client, caloriesToLose: 1 };


// Correct
const UserExtended5: UserExtendedType<UserRole.Client> = { userRole: UserRole.Client, caloriesToLose: 1, readyToTraining: true };
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAqgzsATgJQPYBthQN4CgpQAqiAhgJYhJQC8UA5IEQggAiCCsIILwgLTdANPlAMLoyoAC416gLBBA3CCAOEHaAhEB64AvrlzAAHgAdUiMRRFIAZiQDGWAJLFylRDj7m9ZI2VMlDALihwRiCgHMAbj4IJDIROC8fPxAgvi0kOFQQEnRrCgCvACNUDGASEGDVdW1dfRBDRBNzKAtBYQr7Ajd0XWE4QlQAGVQEL3AILKRggkR8gBMAT070kEyoHLyCorURSYTYBEQAUQ1DEHHgccJ14AAeQihNffG4TaQ0TAA%20cTwCMC3H4C9CXmUoABkUAAFJdrqBbvcUHkAHSzKgAflq8LsXjqQlEAEo1AB6HFQADuiGS-igHweeVwpmSPihuxuRy88CQ9IhRxOCTOzOhmBh9VEL1o2DJnzyTNFvJR3CgjhEzlc7m%209DgKroUGUwVweLJIAA1iBUASQFAXMB0OMqTSxNzWQcjgAmcUsvZs46nLkS4Bw0gUJCCnAiimYJ08r1SmVIOUuNyeZWq6VgPUGo0AMWE5q8dEMPjVGtx%20NN5pNxOgJEJxNiUAMxjMwEtIFpNpddvGAGYQ7bDm7Odyvt6bH7XoHQyG%20%20GWm1gB1ur0lXQVXBc5rtQA5ZImsDodALVBTeuNrado4AFg7za7HPOvdh-Iq-uF5JHUL7t5E0onfinnR6fSgAEZ1U1LV8X4XQxlMER92tQ9zyOABWM8GW7K9PT5DE7yHR8vlHG90LfGVUknacfyVP9pTGEgphmH05liLxfDALANSAA)

Comment: Ок, ща попробую...

Comment: Для задачи я написал упрощённый вариант, но на самом деле мой случай чуть по сложнее и тип User у меня выглядит вот так: `type User = Omit<IUser, 'passwordHash'> & {password: string}`
Пытаюсь сейчас объединить этот тип и ваш вариант с дженериками, пока не очень получается.
Возможно это займёт некоторое время.

Comment: Ну, по текущему условию, об этом было догадаться сложно. Возможно стоит добавить это в вопрос, для лучшего понимания проблемы.

Comment: Если более подробно описывать задачу, то она станет слишком большой. Не буду грузить лишними деталями, в принципе вы ответили на мой вопрос в том виде в котором я его сформулировал, так что приму ваш ответ. А остальное попытаюсь додумать сам :)
Пока склоняюсь к такому варианту:
`interface IUser {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  passwordHash: string;
  role: UserRole;
}

type UserData = Omit<IUser, 'passwordHash'> & {password: string}

export type UserExtendedType<T extends UserRole> = UserData & (T extends UserRole.Trainer ? ITrainer : IClient)`

Comment: Лучше не тащить дженерики туда, где можно обойтись без них.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще-то, на мой взгляд самый нормальный способ - такой: [песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAqgzsATgJQPYBthQN4CgpQAqiAhgJYhJQC8UA5IEQggAiCCsIILwgLTdANPlAMLoyoAC416gLBBA3CCAOEHaAhEB64AvrlzAAHgAdUiMRRFIAZiQDGWAJLFylRDj5gEKDMABcsJ2kwA6axSQA3HzmemRGZKYkhu5wIogUAOZBBBBIZCJwMXGJyVBaSHCoICTofiCJ7gBGqC4kIEGq6tq6+iCGiCbmUBaCwm32BI5IXm4ewy7evaK5kei6wnCEqAAyqAju4BCVgXyIwCQAJgCeS2UVUNW19SpqIkf5Y3a0VqT+dgA+3VNtQUA)

```
enum UserRole {
  Trainer = 'Тренер',
  Client = 'Клиент',
}

export interface ITrainer {
  userRole: UserRole.Trainer;
  certificate: string;
  merits: string;
  personalTraining: boolean;
}

export interface IClient {
  userRole: UserRole.Client;
  caloriesToLose: number;
  readyToTraining: boolean;
}

type User = ITrainer | IClient;
```

Если всё же по какой-то причине не хочется добавлять `userRole` в эти интерфейсы, то можно намутить такое: [песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAqgzsATgJQPYBthQN4CgpQAqiAhgJYhJQC8UA5IEQggAiCCsIILwgLTdANPlAMLoyoAC416gLBBA3CCAOEHaAhEB64AvrlwiAngAcs8KrT4AfHFDAIUGYAC5Y5tJgB0xcpURRlUAGRQAks4pIRiZmSPbWtqGWDoLCIGIe3j4xomrAAB5aqIhiFCJIAGYkAMZYfqQBbngEJdlk+WRFJHk2cCKIFADmANx8EEhkInAtbZ09BDqIcKggJOj+IJ02AEaoliQgPaq46ZnZULkFxaXJcTh8jehZwnCEqAAyqAg24BBLSGNQiMAkACYat-NFlAVmsNiogA)

```
enum UserRole {
  Trainer = 'Тренер',
  Client = 'Клиент',
}

type User = 
  | { userRole: UserRole.Trainer } & ITrainer
  | { userRole: UserRole.Client } & IClient

export interface ITrainer {
  certificate: string;
  merits: string;
  personalTraining: boolean;
}

export interface IClient {
  caloriesToLose: number;
  readyToTraining: boolean;
}
```

Если типов больше, то можно немного упростить (заодно тайпскрипт проконтролирует, что перечислены все роли): [песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAqgzsATgJQPYBthQN4CgpQAqiAhgJYhJQC8UA5IEQggAiCCsIILwgLTdANPlAMLoyoAC416gLBBA3CCAOEHaAhEB64AvrlwiAngAcs8KrTwEA2ogxYKsBCjMBdAFw4oYK2kwPTmKMqgAyHH2M9a0wAOmJySkR7KABJcIokXgJAlzMQwWEQEWiYjNEkrxNbFSMg12AbNWAADy1URDEKESQAMxIAYyw40gTEfwJOhrIWsnaSZoc4EUQKAHMAbj4IJDIROEnpucWCHUQ4VBASdHiQOYcAI1QzEhBF1VwauoaoJtaOrrys-qgx9HrhOCEVAAGVQCAc4Ag5yQ2ygiGAJAAJhogSczlBLtdbipcEA)

```
enum UserRole {
  Trainer = 'Тренер',
  Client = 'Клиент',
}

type User = {
  [role in UserRole]: { userRole: role } & {
    [UserRole.Trainer]: ITrainer,
    [UserRole.Client]: IClient,
  }[role]
}[UserRole]

export interface ITrainer {
  certificate: string;
  merits: string;
  personalTraining: boolean;
}

export interface IClient {
  caloriesToLose: number;
  readyToTraining: boolean;
}
```

Сюда же можно прикрутить общие поля из любого типа: [песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAqgzsATgJQPYBthQN4CgpQAqiAhgJYhJQC8UA5IEQggAiCCsIILwgLTdANPlAMLoyoAC416gLBBA3CCAOEHaAhEB64AvrlwiAngAcsAIRIJ4VWngJgEKDMABcsC2kwBuPulQBzCrbgjEFN84ItAzgAd1REABMACQMACy8fP2dVdW0sAEkjRHEAeQgyEQAefUMLbigAIiC4UPDouIqAPigAMhw+atrIhN8QfxU1TR07Y3aCAG1EKygKEctMAF1bbChzJAcbKCnMKGVWqEyLfdMCKHGsjYA6YnJKRCWDm4okXlOzi6tLwWEQEQf076iV67SZWBYqc72MFqYAADy04TEFBESAAZiQAMYZJ53MZQLGIERkVFkDEkFE9JJ8CBIApwSl9AJQHSIOCoEAkdA4vy2ABGqCsJBAyRh8MRM1+aMxGUBvzxZNcvmAcEIqAAMqgELZwBBeUgmYhgCQIhpVdy+nyBZghSKgA)

```
enum UserRole {
  Trainer = 'Тренер',
  Client = 'Клиент',
}

type BaseUser = {
  userRole: UserRole;
  login: string;
  passwordHash: string;
}

type IUser = Omit<BaseUser, "passwordHash"> & {
  password: string;
}

type User = {
  [role in UserRole]: { userRole: role } & IUser & {
    [UserRole.Trainer]: ITrainer,
    [UserRole.Client]: IClient,
  }[role]
}[UserRole]

export interface ITrainer {
  certificate: string;
  merits: string;
  personalTraining: boolean;
}

export interface IClient {
  caloriesToLose: number;
  readyToTraining: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. Я пока ещё учусь, поэтому не все синтаксические конструкции мне знакомы. Но выглядит довольно интересно, попробую на досуге применить это в своём проекте.